# Periodic table and p block elements

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table

I have two questions:

1. It's said that in p block there's gradation in physical and chemical properties of elements. What is meant by this statement?
2. Why are the different blocks named s, p, d and f?

Answer (score 1):

### First question

From [P.248, Rudiments of Chemistry](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=TVugToBQ694C&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=p+block+gradation&source=bl&ots=ckuywLLhO5&sig=av3x2T_NVHi43VFVeD7S5YuMB4M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj39sOBj_vOAhUCtJQKHSv9C58Q6AEIRTAJ#v=onepage&q=electropositivity%2C%20electronegativity&f=false):

> '*p*' block elements contain both metal and non-metal and we observe a gradation of properties (such as electropositivity, electronegativity, reducing or oxidising property etc.) as we move from left to right in a period.

### Second question

From the [Wikipedia article on atomic orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital):

> They are derived from the description by early spectroscopists of certain series of alkali metal spectroscopic lines as **s**harp, **p**rincipal, **d**iffuse, and **f**undamental. Orbitals for ℓ > 3 continue alphabetically, omitting j (g, h, i, k, …)

Comment: Aren't trends followed in every block?If yes,why did my teacher tell that point only for that specific block?

Comment: @AbhijithDileepKumar That would be something you should ask your teacher.

Comment: I am sorry.But could you tell me what "complexes"are in chemistry?

Comment: @AbhijithDileepKumar Make that a separate question with sufficient context (where do you see this word? can you quote the whole sentence?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_complex